# How exactly RouteFeatureWeightType works?

Tags: here-api

We are trying to achieve a route calculation with preference for "dirt roads". So we tried HERE REST API with routing mode of "car;tollroad:-1,motorway:-1,boatFerry:-1,railFerry:-1,tunnel:-1,dirtRoad:0".

According to docs, "-1" value should only place minor penalties for these road features, not strict exclude them.

It works fine for predefined test cases outside of towns, where there is a "dirt road" route can be plotted.
But in cases of big cities (example: San-Francisco => Indianapolis), API (generally) returns NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED_CHECK_OPTIONS error.

How severe is a penalty of "-1" weight? Is there a better approach for setting up routing preference for "unusual" road types?

Example request: https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=API_KEY&mode=fastest;car;tollroad:-1,motorway:-1,boatFerry:-1,railFerry:-1,tunnel:-1,dirtRoad:0&waypoint0=geo!37.77713,-122.41964&waypoint1=geo!39.76691,-86.14996

Comment: I did a little experiment - changed `car` type to `truck`. This setup returned an actual route and did not return an error, no matter what weights I placed for motorways and tollroads.

So if you really need to use this kind of setup - try `truck` mode instead of `car`. Though I'm not sure, what kind of additional problems you can experience with that vehicle mode, so be warned.

Answer (score 0):

In case of inter-cities, there are mostly motorways, tollroads and almost no dirt roads. Your specification tells the algorithm to avoid tollroads and motorways which results in an impossible or irrelevant route. You need to adjust which route features to avoid/exclude based on the results you receive.

Comment: That is the point - we tried "-2" and "-1" weights for everything except "dirt roads", because we expected to just "assign penalties for links containing the corresponding feature", not strictly exclude them.
What weights should we set up, in order to get a routing algorithm, that prefers "dirt road" type, but is still capable of using other road types as a fallback option?

Comment: I did a little experiment - changed `car` type to `truck`. This setup returned an actual route and did not return an error, no matter what weights I placed for motorways and tollroads.